# How to open an article in android app?

Tags: android, article

Can someone tell me what steps to follow to open an article in android app?

I do not meant open via browser but in-app.

Update description:

I do not mean open the actual website article, but copy the content (along with images, video links) and show it in the app with your preferred font, background etc

Comment: well this is a 'big' general question. i suggest you to go through this http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html?hl=p

Comment: what do you mean by an "article"?  a web page or a PDF file or some document or?

Comment: True, I did not specify. I mean open an article from a webpage, but not the webpage i.e. take all the content and show it in the app in your background, not the website's one...

Comment: did you mean local html content ?

Answer (score 0):

You can open a web page in-app (instead of the browser) by using a `WebView` (see documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)). I recommend also reading the API guide topic [Building Web Apps in WebView](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html).

Answer (score 0):

you may use webview to load your html file

```
WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/file.html");
```